# Ether nomenclature: Oxygens on alkyls and alkyls on alkyls

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

[image: Image 1]

Does the ether hold priority over longest chain? If so, my bet would be on:

**4-(2-ethylheptanyl)oxy decane**

If not, I would say:

**4-(octan-2-yl methoxy) decane**

[image: Image 2]

Again, if ether takes precedence and not longer chain (which, if you ask me, would be ideal), I'd say:

**4-[(1-methyl,2-propylheptan-1-yl)oxy]decane**

If not:

**4-(ethan-1-yl oxy nonan-4-yl)decane**

What is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Names for ethers can be formed by five different methods. Furthermore, various traditional names are retained for use in general nomenclature.

According to the current version of *[Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry – IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names 2013 (Blue Book)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/9781849733069-fp001)*, preferred IUPAC names of ethers $\ce{R-O-R'}$, when $\ce{R}$ and $\ce{R'}$ are both aliphatic groups, are formed by **substitutive nomenclature**. In substitutive nomenclature, when $\ce{R}$ is different from $\ce{R'}$, $\ce{RH}$ is chosen as parent hydride and $\ce{R'-O-{}}$ is cited as a substituent to it.

> **P-63.2.2.1.1** Substituent prefix names for $\ce{R'-O-{}}$ groups are formed by concatenation, i.e., by adding the prefix ‘oxy’ to the substituent prefix name for the group $\ce{R'}$. (…)

For the first example in the question, the name of the parent hydride $\ce{RH}$ is ‘decane’.
The substituent prefix name for the group $\ce{R'-{}}$ is ‘2-ethylheptyl’.
Thus, the substituent prefix names for the $\ce{R'-O-{}}$ group is ‘(2-ethylheptyl)oxy’.
Therefore, the preferred IUPAC name of the compound is ‘4-[(2-ethylheptyl)oxy]decane’.

[image: 4-[(2-ethylheptyl)oxy]decane]

For the second example in the question, the name of the parent hydride $\ce{RH}$ is ‘decane’.
The substituent prefix name for the group $\ce{R'-{}}$ is ‘3-propyloctan-2-yl’.
Thus, the substituent prefix names for the $\ce{R'-O-{}}$ group is ‘(3-propyloctan-2-yl)oxy’.
Therefore, the preferred IUPAC name of the compound is ‘4-[(3-propyloctan-2-yl)oxy]decane’.

[image: 4-[(3-propyloctan-2-yl)oxy]decane]

Comment: Take a look at [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butyl) This Wikipedia article contrasts systematic and alternate notations of butyls. Applying the same to larger alkyls, don't you think that "(1-methyl,2-propylheptyl)oxy" is also a correct name for the alkoxy substituent in the second case?